# Approximating $\prod_{r=s}^t (1-b/r)$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, approximation

I am currently trying to place an order of precision on the approximation $$\prod_{r=s}^t \left(1-\frac{b}{r}\right) \approx \left(\frac{s}{t}\right)^b$$

This follows because $$\prod_{r=s}^t \left(1-\frac{b}{r}\right) = e^{ \sum_{r=s}^t \log\left(1-\frac{b}{r}\right)} \approx e^{-\sum_{r=s}^t \frac{b}{r}} \approx e^{-b(\log t - \log s)}$$ via the Taylor expansion $$\log(1-x) = -x - \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{3} - \cdots$$ and the approximation $$\log t - \log s \approx \sum_{r=s}^t \frac{1}{r}$$

However, I would like to know how accurate the approximation is in terms of $t$, preferably some big O notation estimate.

Comment: Use the next term in the expansion of the logarithm.

Comment: What should I be getting from it? So far I'm just finding that it is pretty much almost constant with respect to $t$. I don't know exactly what the constant is though.